# Spring Cache - real diff between @CachePut and @CacheEvict

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-cache

The more I read about this, the less I know it seems :).

Just one quick question, what to use on **update** method if I want **listAll** to be refreshed with the new stuff from the update? What's safer/better practice, evict or cacheput? It's a little confusing to me, and I read 15 tabs. :D 
I will have **delete** as well, there I assume to be required just CacheEvict, right?

```
@Cacheable(CACHE1)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object listAll(@Valid  @RequestParam("status") String status) {
   //code
    }

 @CachePut(CACHE1)
//or
 @CacheEvict(value = {CACHE1}, allEntries = true)
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public Object update(@RequestBody Project project{
    //code
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use CachePut when you're saving an object and  CacheEvict when you're deleting an object.  You could conceivable just evict on save too and let the Cacheable annotation on your getters handle fetching fresh data and re-cacheing it and avoid using CachePut altogether.

Comment: Thanks. Are the both options equally fast and reliable?

Comment: Cacheing operations will always be faster than fetching from the DB.  I assume you're using EHCache or something similar for the caching engine.  I've written large applications utilizing those and they're fantastic.  Just don't have multiple methods that might bypass the cache.

Comment: I have 30 controllers, and each one of them have listAll, update(insert) and delete. So I'am afraid of using cacheput, in sense something will go the wrong way and show incorect data on frontend :/

Comment: If they're all referencing the same object/service to handle data operations you should be fine. If they're not, then you have a design problem.  Keep in mind, in order for the Caching annotations to work, they have to be access via Spring, not directly.